# Unicorn vs Puma in clustered mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server, unicorn, puma

I've always used `unicorn` as my application server but relatively recently I noticed that `puma` now has the `clustered mode`, so I wonder if there is any reason to use `puma` in the `clustered mode` instead of `unicorn` considering that my code is not thread-safe and therefore I can't use threads?

- I am using MRI 2.2

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your application to a certain degree. If it has lots of long-running requests you may see some benefit, but if that's the case it sounds like Thin is a better option given your constraints.

Puma performs very well with Rubinius or JRuby; the GVL in MRI will cause it not to perform as well with MRI. As such you won't see a performance benefit from switching away from Unicorn if your application is primarily serving up fast responses (API server, for example).

There's some formal benchmarking [here](https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/ruby-app-server-arena-pt1) and [here](https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/ruby-app-server-arena-pt2).

Comment: I can't use neither puma with threads (the code is not thread-safe) nor thin (the code is not written in the evented style). I have a vanilla rails app and I wonder if there's any difference in performance between let's say having 3 workers of unicorn and 3 workers of puma each with 1 thread?